# Could Not Match Expected Type Integer with actual type float

Tags: haskell

```
countSequences :: Int -> Int -> Integer

countSequences 0 m = 0
countSequences m 0 = 0
countSequences (n) (m) =  if (n <= (m+1)) then (truncate((cee (m+1) (n) (0))) + truncate((countSequences (fromIntegral (n-1)) (fromIntegral (m))))) 
else truncate(countSequences (fromIntegral (n-1)) (fromIntegral (m)))

factorial :: Float -> Float
factorial 0 = 1
factorial 1 = 1
factorial x = x * factorial(x-1)

cee :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float

cee x y z = if (x==y) then ((1) / (factorial ((x+z)-(y)))) else ((x) * (cee (x-1) (y) (z+1)))
```

i cant really understand why this error keep coming up .. the truncate is supposed to convert the type from Float to Integer so ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is of type `Int` (per your type signature for `countSequences`: hence, so is `m + 1`. However, your function `cee` expects a `Float`, so the type checker righteously complains.

Furthermore, you will need a couple of more fixes to make this type check. Here's a version that passes the checker:

```
countSequences :: Int -> Int -> Integer
countSequences 0 m = 0
countSequences m 0 = 0
countSequences n m =
  if   n <=  m + 1
  then truncate $
         cee (fromIntegral (m+1)) (fromIntegral n) 0 +
         fromIntegral (countSequences (n-1) m)
  else countSequences (n-1) m
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type `Int'
In the first argument of `(+)', namely `m'
In the first argument of `cee', namely `(m + 1)'
In the first argument of `truncate', namely
  `((cee (m + 1) (n) (0)))'
```

You see, the problem is you passing an `Int` to the function `cee`.

Here, I cleaned up the code for you:

```
countSequences :: Int -> Int -> Integer

countSequences 0 m = 0
countSequences m 0 = 0
countSequences n m = 
  if n <= m+1
  then truncate (cee (fromIntegral (m+1)) (fromIntegral n) 0) +
       countSequences (n-1) m
  else countSequences (n-1) m

factorial :: Float -> Float
factorial 0 = 1
factorial 1 = 1
factorial x = x * factorial (x-1)

cee :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float

cee x y z =
  if (x==y)
  then 1 / factorial (x+z-y)
  else x * cee (x-1) y (z+1)
```

Comment: `fromIntegral m+1` should probably be `fromIntegral m + 1` or `fromIntegral (m+1)`, since it's such a common mistake to not realise that application binds tightest :)

Comment: @ehird: you're right. I got lazy and just used the convenient fact that `(fromIntegral x) + 1 == fromIntegral (x+1)`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Technically, for sufficiently pathological `x` you could get an overflow pre-conversion, which would probably result in different results since Float doesn't overflow in the same way... but yes, close enough for all reasonable values :)